# Collabnet post-commit hook fails to execute Perl script

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, svn, collabnet

I'm trying to set up the Slack Subversion integration.  I use Collabnet Edge under Windows. The Slack site suggests a Perl script ([Here](https://github.com/tinyspeck/services-examples/blob/master/subversion.pl)) to call.  I've installed [Dwimperl](http://dwimperl.com/), and written a batch file to run the script, passing the parameters to the perl script.  This all works correctly if I call it manually from the commandline, however when it's called by Subversion something clearly goes amiss as I don't see anything in my Slack channels.

The batch file has one line:

```
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe C:\csvn\data\repositories\repo\hooks\slacknotify.pl %1 %2
```

I've verified that the hook is being called after a commit by echoing %1 and %2 to a file, and that behaves as I expect.

My guess is that Subversion calls the batch file without some environment vars set, or something along those lines, but I'm completely unfamiliar with Perl and I don't know which.  I'm calling the perl executable by absolute path, so even if %PATH% is blank I think it should work.

A related question is: how do I go about debugging issues like this?  The Collabnet log files have nothing in them than I can see

Comment: What happens when you run the script on the command line, passing in the real values of `%1` and `%2` as arguments?

Comment: Both the batch file and the perl script behave correctly if I run them from the command line and pass the same args that svn does

Answer (score 0):

In this case it was simply the PATH variable that needed setting.  Specifically

```
SET PATH=C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin;C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\bin;C:\Dwimperl\c\bin
```

at the start of the batch file has solved the problem.